# WPF Binding to alternate static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, staticresource

I am attempting to bind a static resource to a view model item based on the state of the item.  There is in a list of items in the view.

The ViewModel has a boolean property State.
The View has a ItemsControl bound to an ObservableCollection

I have two resource strings defined for each of the items required.
How do I display the correct string based on the value of State?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

To use the static resource you can use `ObjectDataProvider`. And to bind it to your View based on the boolean value, you can use proper `Converter`

Comment: I think I simplified my example too much.  But you got me thinking in a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use Binding with a Converter.

Here is an example:

```
<config:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="Bool2Brush"
                      TrueBrush="{StaticResource OKStatusBrush}"
                      FalseBrush="{StaticResource ErrorStatusBrush}" />

<TextBlock Name="tbx1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
    Background="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Brush}}"...
```

See how you can enable your custom converter to accept resources? Simply define converter in resources too and reference the two you need. Then let the Binding know about your converter.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  What I really wanted was to be able to do that, but use viewmodel bindings to determine the value of the static resources.

Comment: Then you will need ContentTemplateSelector that selects you templates based on content. Name says everything lol http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx