# Bind to parent DataContext of TreeViewItem BUT TreeView's DataContext for top-most items

Tags: xaml, data-binding, treeview, datacontext

I have a `TreeView` that is using a single `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. I know how to bind to a property of the parent `TreeViewItem` in a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
<Button
  Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveCommand,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=2,
                            AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"
  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementId}" />
```

However, this does of course not work for the top-most items, since there is no ancestor `TreeViewItem` - here, I want to use the `DataContext` of the `TreeView` itself. How can I bind the command to the `TreeView`'s `DataContext` for the top-most elements of the tree view? If necessary, you can assume that the view model has a property of the same name as the hierarchical view models representing each tree item.

Comment: I used `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}` for the topmost items. I modified the SubModelCollection demo of Elmish.WPF to use one HierarchicalDataTemplate for the topmost items, and one for child items with your original command binding.

Comment: I am also trying to figure out if alternate bindings are possible, because that might be even simpler. Haven't had time to study this link thoroughly yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408502/wpf-binding-to-alternate-static-resource

Comment: Thanks! Could you point me to a repo where I can see the changes you made?

Comment: I don't have a public repo, but I'll paste in the only file that was modified as an answer here. Also, after playing with it for a while, I noticed there are problems. The F# stuff works somehow, but WPF isn't quite happy with what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is my modified MainWindow.xaml based on the SubModelCollection example of Elmish.WPF (repo on GitHub), that demonstrates how I thought I solved the problem. As I mentioned in the comment to the OP, I encountered a new problem with this solution, but I hope it can be ironed out without too much effort. I have a feeling it's a trivial problem that remains.

My intention here is that one HierarchicalDataTemplate will be used for the top level items, and another for all other items. To my surprise it looks like it actually works as far as manipulating the data correctly, and the buttons work on all levels, but WPF is not happy with what's going on. Nodes on level two collapses visually when I add, remove or move subnodes below them, and the Output pane in VS has something to tell:

"System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
"

I had the same kind of error before introducing SharedPart, so I don't think that's causing it.

This is MainWindow.xaml, the only file I modified.

```
<Window
x:Class="Elmish.WPF.Samples.SubModelCollection.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Single counter" Height="800" Width="1000"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SharedPart">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CounterId}" Width="250" Margin="10,5,10,5" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CounterValue, StringFormat='Counter value: {0}'}" Width="100" Margin="0,5,10,5" />
            <Button Command="{Binding Decrement}" Content="-" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="30" />
            <Button Command="{Binding Increment}" Content="+" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="30" />
            <Button Command="{Binding Reset}" Content="Reset" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="50" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StepSize, StringFormat='Step size: {0}'}" Margin="0,5,10,5" />
            <Slider Value="{Binding StepSize}" TickFrequency="1" Maximum="10" Minimum="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Width="100" Margin="0,5,10,5" />
            <Button Command="{Binding AddChild}" Content="Add child" Margin="0,5,10,5" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level2Data" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildCounters}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SharedPart}"/>
            <Button
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.Remove, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=2}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding CounterId}"
                        Content="×" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="20" />
            <Button
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.MoveUp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=2}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding CounterId}"
                        Content="↑" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="20" />
            <Button
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.MoveDown, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=2}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding CounterId}"
                        Content="↓" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level1Data" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildCounters}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level2Data}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SharedPart}"/>
            <Button
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.Remove, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding CounterId}"
                        Content="×" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="20" />
            <Button
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.MoveUp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding CounterId}"
                        Content="↑" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="20" />
            <Button
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.MoveDown, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding CounterId}"
                        Content="↓" Margin="0,5,10,5" Width="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,10">
    <Button Command="{Binding AddCounter}" Content="Add counter" Width="150" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Counters}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Level1Data}">
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Would there be any way of doing this without duplication of the template contents?

Comment: I hope so, which is why I am looking at "alternate bindings", though I'm pessimistic at that particular route. Also googled single hidden root, but that looked like a dead end - might have found something, but with serious drawbacks.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to set a binding higher up in each HierarchicalDataTemplate, for the buttons to use, so that they too can be moved into the SharedPart. I'm not very familiar with WPF/XAML, so will have to spend some time googling that.

Comment: I wonder whether things would work if instead of Key the DataType was used in the templates. For that I need to turn around the dependency between the XAML and the F# source. Will try this when I can find the time to do it.